# What can be said about the sets $A$ and $B$ if $A \Delta B = A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is this question just asking what $A$ and $B$ are?

Like, $A = (A – B) \cup (B – A)$?

Or should I be writing a proof of some sort?

Comment: You should be writing a proof.  Put together some examples and I think you'll see you can characterize $A$ and $B$ rather simply.

Comment: There are four possibilities for an element to be in or out of $A,B$.  Try them all.  Which work?

Comment: Yes, you should prove that $A\Delta B=A$ if and only if $B= ?$

Comment: In other words, **sove the equation for $B$". Do you know that $(X\Delta Y)\Delta Z=X\Delta(Y\Delta Z)$? Do you know what $A\Delta A$ is?

Comment: @bof   If and only if B is not a subset of A?

Comment: if and only if $B=\emptyset$

Comment: @bof But isn't A everything in B and A but not what's in both of them? And wouldn't both include the empty set?

Comment: $$A\Delta\emptyset=(A\setminus\emptyset)\cup(\emptyset\setminus A)=A\cup\emptyset=A$$ $$A\Delta\emptyset=(A\cup\emptyset)\setminus(A\cap\emptyset)=A\setminus\emptyset=A$$ $$A\Delta B=A\implies B=\emptyset\Delta B=(A\Delta A)\Delta B=A\Delta(A\Delta B)=A\Delta A=\emptyset$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A \Delta B = A$ iff $B=\emptyset$. $\Delta$ forms a commutative group where each element is self-inverse and the neutral element is $\emptyset$.

And in such a group: $a+b=a\implies 0= a+a =a+ a+b = 0+b = b$

Or low level: if $x \in B$ then either $x \in A$ and then $x \notin A \Delta B=A$ contradiction or $x \notin A$ and then $x \in A \Delta B =A$ also contradiction. So no $x \in B$ can exist.